# How to add table rows to an existing table in HTML using JavaScript without insertRow?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I have an assignment where if I pass an array of 0s into a function, I need to add only **one** row to an existing table. However, when I run my code through the assignment checker, it keeps saying that I am making two rows. As a result, I keep failing the unit test.

The assignment also notes that I am not allowed to use insertCell and/or insertRow as it causes a problem with the auto-grader.

My approach to this problem is that if the sum of the array is equal to 0, get the existing table which has an id of `distributionTable` and append a single row to it. I used the browser inspect tool in order to debug to ensure that one row is present in the HTML.

Below is the function I created in JavaScript:

```
function setTableContent(userInput) {
    let gradeArray = parseScores(userInput);
    let distArray = buildDistributionArray(gradeArray);
    let sum = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < distArray.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + distArray[i];
    }

    if (sum <= 0) {
        var table = document.getElementById("distributionTable")
        row = table.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
    } 
}
```

Below is the provided HTML page that will be modified from the JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .bar0 { vertical-align: bottom; background-color: #00C000; }
            .bar1 { vertical‐align: bottom; background-color: #309000; }
            .bar2 { vertical‐align: bottom; background-color: #606000; }
            .bar3 { vertical‐align: bottom; background-color: #903000; }
            .bar4 { vertical‐align: bottom; background-color: #C00000; }
            td { vertical-align: bottom }
        </style>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="bodyLoaded()">
        <table style="border: 2px solid black" id="distributionTable">
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the HTML elements in my browser after running the code:
[image: HTML Inspect Code]

Here is the output from the unit test: 
[image: Unit Test Result]

Please let me know if you have any other questions or suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auto-grader seems to be confused.

Im willing to bet the grader is checking `table.childNodes.length` instead of `table.children.length`.

It should only be checking children and not childNodes.

Edit: 
And just to be done with the assignment (while they fix the grader) you could just do the following

```
table.innerHTML = "";
table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
```